# Riemann Surface of an Annulus

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces

Could someone please show me how to prove this step by step? This is a Practice Question for the final exam but we barely touched on Riemann Surface in the lectures X.X'

Thanks! Especially how to construct charts and the biholomorphic functions.

> Let $\lambda > 1$. Consider the Riemann surface defined as
>
> $$X := \mathbb{H} \big / \sim$$
>
> where $z \sim w$ if and only if $w = \lambda^n z$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.
> Prove that $X$ is a Riemann surface, and show that it is isomorphic to the annulus
>
> $$A_R := \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \ : \ 1 < |z| < R \}$$
>
> for some value of $R$. Find $R$ as a function of $\lambda$.

Comment: The multiplication by $\lambda$ sends  the annulus $|z| \in (r_1,r_2)$ to $|z| \in (|\lambda| r_1,|\lambda| r_2)$

Comment: Wait, what is $\mathbb{H}$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 Upper half plane.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question!

It shouldn't be hard to see that $X$ is a Riemann surface, and one shouldn't need to resort to explicit holomorphic charts.  The idea is that $\mathbb{H}$ is a complex surface, and we are quotienting it by a map $z \mapsto \lambda z$ that preserves this complex structure.  In other words, we can regard sufficiently small neighborhoods of $\mathbb{H}$ as charts on $X$, and the transition functions will be of the form $z \mapsto \lambda^n z$ which is holomorphic.

Now we want to classify the resulting Riemann surface $X$.  Generally, it's hard to obtain an explicit uniformization map, and I haven't thought enough to see whether it's doable in this case.  But one can proceed indirectly.  Firstly, observe that from the description $X = {\mathbb{H}/\sim}$ it is manifest that $\pi_1(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.  Any doubly-connected Riemann surface is isomorphic to either $\mathbb{C}^*$, $\Delta^*$, or an annulus $A_R$ for $1 < R < \infty$ (as defined in your question).  We can distinguish these by their modulus.

In the metric $\rho = \lvert dz \rvert/\lvert z \rvert$, $X$ is presented as a right cylinder with circumference $\log \lambda$ and height $\pi$.  To see this, note that $\{z \in \mathbb{H} \mid 1 \leq \lvert z \rvert \leq \lambda\}$ is a fundamental domain for $X$.  The circumference is computed by the hyperbolic distance from $i$ to $\lambda i$ along the vertical geodesic, and the height can be computed as the length of the semicircular arc joining $-1$ and $1$, where the hyperbolic metric coincides with the Euclidean metric.  Anyway, we find that the modulus of $X$ is given by $\pi/\log \lambda$.

On the other hand, the modulus of $A_R$ is $\frac{\log R}{2\pi}$.  So solving for $R$ we find that $R = e^{2\pi^2/\log \lambda}$.

Comment: Hello JHF, thanks for your reply! I have heard of using modulus to find the universal cover. Would you have some links or references where I can learn more about it? Also, would you please explain how you got the modulus of X and A_R? Thank you!

Comment: The modulus of a cylinder is just its height divided by its circumference. I learnt this material myself from C. McMullen, who has wonderful course notes on his website.  Also, I think Appendix B of Milnor's *Dynamics in One Complex Variable* also contains everything I used; example B.5 summarizes my answer.

Comment: For the last part. $\varphi (z)=\frac{2\pi}{\log \lambda }(\pi+i\log z)$ maps $\{z\mid 1<|z|\le \lambda ,\,z\in \mathbb{H}\}$ onto a rectangle with vertices $0$, $\frac{2\pi^2}{\log \lambda },$ $ \frac{2\pi^2}{\log \lambda }+2\pi i$ and $2\pi i$. Furtheremore $e^z $ maps this rectangle onto an annulus $\{z\mid 1<|z|<e^{\frac{2\pi^2}{\log \lambda }}\}.$ So $R=e^{\frac{2\pi^2}{\log \lambda }}.$