# Circle length in hyperbolic annuli

Tags: complex-analysis, riemannian-geometry

$\renewcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}\renewcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}$In a short paper by H. Renggli, *On holomorphic mappings of annuli into annuli*, 1976, I found the following passage:

> Let $A$ denote the annulus $\{ z \in \mathbb C: 0 < r < |z| < R \}$. Using a conformal mapping of the universal covering surface of $A$ onto the unit disk one defines in $A$ a non-Euclidean metric (with constant Gaussian curvature $-1$).

The universal covering surface of $A$ is just the strip
$$S = \{\, z \in \mathbb C : -\log R < \Im z < -\log r \,\},$$
and the covering map is given by $z \mapsto e^{iz}$. I'm not entirely sure how Renggli wants to proceed here. Of course by the Riemann mapping theorem, there exists a biholomorphic map $S \to \mathbb D = \{z \in \mathbb C : |z| < 1\}$, and we can use this to pull-back the hyperbolic metric from $\mathbb D$ to $S$. However, it is not clear at all if this metric descends to $A$.

*Question 1.* Is it possible to write down a biholomorphic map $S \to \mathbb D$ explicitly?

My idea to obtain a hyperbolic metric on $A$ is the following: The shift $S + i\log R$ is contained in the upper half plane $\mathbb H = \{z \in \mathbb C : \Im z > 0\}$, so that we may restrict the hyperbolic metric on $\mathbb H$,
$$ds^2 = \frac{dx^2 + dy^2}{y^2}$$
to $S + i\log R$. Since this metric is invariant under the group of deck transformations $\operatorname{Deck} = \{\,  z\mapsto z + 2\pi k : k \in \mathbb Z\}$, it descends indeed to $A$. In that setting however, $S$ does not map *onto* the unit disk.

Anyway, in the following Renggli claims that the circle
$$z(t) = \sqrt{Rr} e^{it}, \quad 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$$
in $A$ has length
$$\label{eq:1}L = \frac{2\pi^2}{\log \frac R r}.\tag{1}$$

*Question 2.* How can I see this?

Suppose I have any circle $t \mapsto \rho e^{it}$ with $r < \rho < R$. This lifts to the curve $t \mapsto t + i (\log \frac R \rho)$ in $S + i \log R$. Hence the length of that curve should be
$$L = \frac{2\pi}{(\log \frac R \rho)^2} = \frac{2\pi}{\big(\log \frac {\sqrt R}{\sqrt r}\big)^2} = \frac{8 \pi}{\big(\log \frac{R}{r}\big)^2},$$
where I have substituted $\rho = \sqrt{Rr}$. This seems to be at odds with \eqref{eq:1}, though. Is my calculation correct?

Answer (score 0):

You need to rescale your $S+ i \log R$ by $\frac{\pi}{\log \frac{R}r}$ to get to the strip
$$
S_0 = \{z\,|\,\operatorname{Im} z\in (0, \pi)\},
$$
which can be mapped to the upper half-plane ${\mathbb H}$ by the exponential function.

The final section map is
$$
f: A\to {\mathbb H};\ z \mapsto e^{i\pi\frac{\log\frac{z}{r}}{\log\frac{R}{r}}}.
$$
Note that $\log\frac{z}{r}$ is well defined up to adding a multiple of $2\pi i$, and that would multiply the image by
$$
e^{i\pi \frac{i2\pi}{\log\frac{R}{r}}} = e^{-\frac{2\pi^2}{ \log\frac{R}{r}}}. 
$$

Of course, it is the inverse of this that is the covering map ${\mathbb H}\to A$. So to summarize,
$$
A = {\mathbb H}/(w \sim \lambda w),\ \lambda = e^{\frac{2\pi^2}{ \log\frac{R}{r}}}>1,
$$
as discussed in many posts, for example, [Riemann Surface of an Annulus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2237251/riemann-surface-of-an-annulus).

Note that this $\lambda$ is apparently related to the arc-length (1) of the middle circle in the post.

To be concrete, let me compute the length of the middle circle
$$
z(t)=\sqrt{Rr}e^{it},\quad 0\leq t\leq 2\pi.
$$
The image is the curve
$$
w(t)=e^{i\pi\frac{\log\Big(\sqrt{\frac{R}{r}} e^{it}\Big)}{\log\frac{R}{r}}} =e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi t}{\log\frac{R}{r}}}=ie^{-\frac{\pi t}{\log\frac{R}{r}}}, \quad 0\leq t\leq 2\pi.
$$
So the image curve lies on the $y$-axis in $\mathbb H$ between $ie^{-\frac{2\pi^2}{\log\frac{R}{r}}}$ and $i$. Note the hyperbolic length on the $y$-axis from $ia$ to $ib$ is
$$
\int_a^b \frac{dy}y = \log \frac{b}{a},\quad 0<a\leq b.
$$
So the length we are after is
$$
\frac{2\pi^2}{\log\frac{R}{r}}
$$
as desired.

To be complete, I also write down the induced hyperbolic metric from
$$
\frac{|dw|}{\operatorname{Im} w} \quad\text{on}\quad {\mathbb H}
$$
to the annulus $A=\{z\,|\, r<|z|<R\}$ as
$$
\frac{\frac{\pi}{\log\frac{R}{r}}}{\sin\Big(\frac{\pi}{\log\frac{R}{r}}\log\frac{|z|}{r}\Big)}\frac{|dz|}{|z|}.
$$
Note that if $R=1$ and we let $r\to 0^+$, this approaches the standard hyperbolic metric on the unit punctured disk as
$$
\frac{|dz|}{\big|\log|z|\big||z|},
$$
by
$$
\sin\Big(\pi\frac{\log|z|-\log r}{-\log r}\Big) = \sin\Big(\pi\frac{\log|z|}{\log r}\Big) \sim  \pi\frac{\log|z|}{\log r}$$
as $r\to 0^+$, since $\sin(\theta + \pi)=-\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: There are a few fishy details in your post, like $S_0$ is a subset of $\mathbb H$, it doesn't map to $\mathbb H$ via the exponential map, and $\mathbb H$ is not a covering of $A$. Also I don't know what you mean by "which now lies on the $y$-axis".

Comment: Doing the calculation, I get the same length $$\frac{8\pi}{\Big(\log \frac R r \Big)^2}$$ as before. This makes sense, since if $S_a = \{z \,|\, 0 < \operatorname{Im}(z) < a\} \subset \mathbb H$ is a strip, and $S_b$ similarly, with scaling map $\varphi: S_a \to S_b, z \mapsto \frac b a z$, then pulling-back the hyperbolic metric on $S_b$ along $\varphi$ to $S_a$ just gives the ordinary hyperbolic metric on $S_a$.

Comment: @red_trumpet So it all boils down to if $\exp: S_0 \to {\mathbb H}$. This is a biholomorphism. The image has arguments from 0 to $\pi$, and that is exactly the upper half plane. The inverse is the principle Log.

Comment: @red_trumpet I added more details and results to make it complete.